# What is the grammatically correct sentence (which or where)?

Tags: grammar, where

Of these two sentences, is there a grammatically correct sentence?

1. This is the point beyond where we have never been.
2. This is the point beyond which we have never been.

and if possible, I would like an explanation.

Comment: "Which" is the logical choice, since it has "point" as antecedent and functions as comp of "beyond". "Where" on the other hand is a locative adjunct meaning "in/at/to (the) point".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, and so far as I can tell, *beyond* won't take PP complements.

Comment: @touchstone It's interesting that both are grammatical for you. It means there must be a dialectical split. The *where* version's ungrammatical for me. Re *which* and *where*, most modern  academic grammars of English (as opposed to dictionaries using 18th century grammar) regard *which* as a pronoun and *where* as an intransitive preposition.

Answer (score 1):

As a British English speaker, the correct answer for me is "beyond which".
The object in question is one of an assumed array of unique points and the speaker is specifying which of those points is the furthest yet visited.

Answer (score -1):

Both would seem equally acceptable grammatically ('the point where ...' is very common, and 'the point at which ...') reasonably so, according to [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+point+where%2Cthe+point+at+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20at%20which%3B%2Cc0).

However,  'the point beyond which' is far more idiomatic than 'the point beyond where' according to [these Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=point+beyond+where%2Cpoint+beyond+which%2Cthe+point+beyond+where%2Cthe+point+beyond+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoint%20beyond%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoint%20beyond%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20beyond%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20beyond%20which%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpoint%20beyond%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoint%20beyond%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20beyond%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20point%20beyond%20which%3B%2Cc0).

This I can only put down to idiosyncrasy. But a 'point' should perhaps be seen more as a metaphorical description of a location (contrast a 'place'), though 'beyond' is truly locative / directional in its prototypical usage.

Comment: Edwin, I think you need to add the "beyond" to your engram search; the fragments you used are perfectly valid in many parts of speech, but only one is correct in conjunction with "beyond" :)

Comment: I was arguing from similar usages with the first four ngrams. I **did** add in the beyond in the final two.